# Pass a resource in URI as a parameter Ruby API

Tags: ruby, url

I hope this is not a question dealing with passing a parameter in a URL.

I have a Put request. The following code adds a user named "Johndoe" in the server. It is NOT like name ?= 'JohnDoe' (not passed as a parameter)

```
uri = URI.parse('http://localhost:15672/api/users/JohnDoe/')
```

I would like to have the JohnDoe or any name passed from a function like,

```
def test_add_user(username,password)
uri = URI.parse('http://localhost:15672/api/users/**username**/')
```

The username in the URL is the username getting added as a user in the server. I suppose the username is not a URI parameter since the 'name' part looks like a resource to me. I tried the following code but in vain

```
uri.join('http://localhost:15672/api/users/',username)
```

Also I tried this

```
username = 'john/'
uri.join('http://localhost:15672/api/users/',username)
```

Any fixes or any alternative ideas as to how I can pass the name?

Regards

Karthik

Comment: Have you tried interpolation? like this: `uri = URI.parse("http://localhost:15672/api/users/#{username}")` . Notice the quotes are double.

Comment: I'm happy when I can help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be done by interpolation of `username`, like this:

```
uri = URI.parse("http://localhost:15672/api/users/#{username}")
```